# How do I lock down nginx on debian wheezy (running systemd)?

Tags: nginx, debian, systemd

The systemd unit file that comes with the nginx-common package runs the master process as root, which makes me nervous.

I assume the only reason it runs as root is to bind port 80, but being root is overkill for that, so I am running it as a normal user and giving it the `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` capability.

I have tweaked the unit file to look like this:

```
[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/nginx/nginx.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;' -s reload
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/nginx -s quit
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
Capabilities=cap_net_bind_service+=ep
user=www-data
```

Are there any downsides to this approach? Does nginx expect to be root for some other reason? Is there a better way to lock down nginx? I know some people like to chroot it but that seems like a lot of hassle.

Comment: I'm curious. Do you have this working? I've tried it but couldn't get it working with fedora 19. Directly running setcap did the trick however.

Comment: It has always seemed to work fine, but I still don't know whether it could have introduced some obscure problem or security vulnerability... hence the question ;)

Answer (score 5):

The master process has to be run as root, otherwise nginx won't be able to bind to port 80, as this is a privileged port.

http://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html

You should instead make sure that the worker processes use a different user. This user can be specified in your `nginx.conf`.

Comment: If you have the `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` capability then you don't need to be root to bind a privileged port.